# Correct vertical spacing before colored theorem with \textcolor

Tags: spacing, color, theorems, vertical-spacing

I have noticed that I get extra vertical space right above any theorem-like environment that is colored using `\textcolor`.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

Some more text.

\textcolor{red}{
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Can anybody explain me why this happens?

Comment: Just use `{\color{red}
\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}}`.

Comment: \textcolor starts a paragraph, you would get a similar spacing with `\leavevmode`.

Comment: @Bernard It works in the example, but I still get unwanted extra space between theorem-like environments, e.g., if I have a colored theorem in between two black ones.

Comment: That is normal : each theorem has a spacing before and a spacing after, so they add. At the end of the back theorem above, you may add `\vspace{-3pt} `  to neutralise it, and similarly at the end of the coloured theorem.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for the help! Adding `\vspace{-3pt}` at the end of the black theorem above and at the end of the colored theorem reduces the extra spacing, but it does not neutralize it completely.

Comment: @Bernard You answer solves the specific issue posed in the question, but would you mind writing a few words on why this happens? So that I could understand also similar cases.

Comment: The values I suggest are described in the amsthm documentation. However, I did not looked at the exact value in the code of the `amsart` class, so you may try with a slighly bigger values. It also may be dues to rubber lengths in the page (to test this hypothesis, add `\raggedbottom at the end of the preamble).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used `\color{red}` and add a pair of braces to make it local, or, if you don't want  to repeat it, define with `thmtools` a new  coloured theorem, using the same counter as `theorem`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\usepackage{thmtools}
\declaretheorem[sibling = theorem, title =Theorem, preheadhook = \color{blue}]{colourthm}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

Some more text.

{\color{red}
\begin{theorem}
One has $1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{theorem}}

Some more text.

\begin{colourthm}One has $2 + 2 = 4$.
\end{colourthm}

Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With a current LaTeX you could add color with a hook:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
Some text.

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

Some more text.

\AddToHookNext{env/theorem/begin}{\color{red}}
\begin{theorem}
aa
\end{theorem}

Some more text.

\begin{theorem}
aa
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]